# Calculate how many times is the first column greater than or equal to the second column using R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to calculate how how many times is the first column greater than or equal to
the second column of the matrix using R.

I have done the following:

```
set.seed(123)
x = matrix(rnorm(4*4,mean=10,sd=2),nrow=4)
x
x[,1]>x[,2]
```

But I cant figure out how to count the times that the column 1 is greater than column 2, I have used function length but it didn't work out.

thank you!

Comment: `sum(x[,1]>x[,2])`

Comment: Do you want to compare each value in the column with another? what is your expected output? Do you mean `sum(x[,1]>x[,2])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logicals can be converted to numbers, `TRUE` as one, `FALSE` to zero, therefore:

```
sum(x[,1] > x[,2])
```